# I wonder how is second 'return' works - return len(A) + 1

Tags: python-3.x

This is a coding lesson from Github.
I wonder how the second return, `return len(A) + 1` works.

list A is made form 1 to N+1 **with 1 number missing**

N is number 0 - 100000

ever number in list A is different

The solution is find the missing number.

```
def solution(A):
    index_dict = {index+1: value for index, value in enumerate(A)}
    value_dict = {value: index+1 for index, value in enumerate(A)}
    for k in index_dict:
        if k not in value_dict:
            return k
    return len(A) + 1
```

I figured out until `return k`. wondering how the `return len(A) + 1` works

Thank you in advance for any answers.

Comment: The second return will be executed if none of the members of `index_dict` are in `value_dict`.

Comment: What problem is it a solution to?

Answer (score 1):

The last line, `return len(A) + 1` is the value that will be returned if all of the values of `index_dict` can be found from `value_dict`. Thus it will fall back to returning the value of `N + 1`, because it had to be the one that was missing from the list.

The solution can actually be even simplified and made more efficient by using `set`s instead of `dict`s:

```
def solution(A):
    index_set = {index + 1 for index, _ in enumerate(A)}
    value_set = {value for value in A}
    for k in index_set:
        if k not in value_set:
            return k
    return len(A) + 1
```

Then we also notice that we can remove the set comphrenesion and just call `set(A)` and that we can replace the `index_set` with a `range` object:

```
def solution(A):
    set_A = set(A)  # store this, so it doesn't have to be recomputed on every loop
    for k in range(1, len(A) + 1):
        if k not in set_A:
            return k
    return len(A) + 1
```

We can also just increase the range by 1 and remove the last `return` completely. This solution is actually way more effiecient than the original one and is around 7x faster on my machine:

```
def solution(A):
    set_A = set(A)
    for k in range(1, len(A) + 2):
        if k not in set_A:
            return k
```

Not gonna get more efficient than that, but just for fun, we can make a `set` out of the `range`, and return the single element that's left over from the `difference` of that and `set(A)`:

```
def solution(A):
    return set(range(1, len(A) + 2)).difference(set(A)).pop()
```